# odoo: how to add computed field with search in a model

Tags: python, odoo, computed-field

In `hr.employee model`, how can I calculate the computed field with amount field in `hr.payslip.input` and `hr.payslip.line`?

1. Employees who completed more than 12 months,
2. from model *hr.payslip.input* sum of *Amount* **where input_type_id = 12** (Provident Fund) and from model *hr.payslip.line* sum of *Amount* **where input_type_id = 26** (Leave Encashment) and plus both amount field's sum
3. Then calculate 75% of final value

Wants to add through Settings -> Technical -> Models.

I tried below to check what I can do, but it's not working, definitely I am not a Python guy (background is Oracle) field **x_loan_applicable_amount** added in employee model.

```
def compute_loan_applicable_amount(self):
    input_amt = self.env['hr.payslip.input']
    for rec in self:
        applicable_amount = 0
        input_ids = input_amt.search([('payslip_id.employee_id', '=', rec.id)])
        if input_ids:
            for inputs in input_ids:
                # amount = payment amount
                applicable_amount += inputs.amount
        
        rec['x_loan_applicable_amount'] = applicable_amount
```

kindly help.

Comment: i have tried this too but it is throwing error, saying emp_id has value NewId_234 
and if this will work how i can get Value in x_loan_applicable amount?
....
for rec in self:
    emp_id = rec.id
    emp_idx = int("".join(filter(str.isdigit, emp_id)))
    applicable_amount = 0
    self.env.cr.execute("""select * from emp_other_amount where employee_id =%s"""%(emp_idx))
    applicable_data = self.env.cr.fetchall()
    rec.x_loan_applicable_amount = applicable_data.applicable_amount